# Workaround for Multiple Policy Based VPN on a VNET

Tags: azure, site-to-site-vpn

I've been struggling with some practical limitations on Azure and some on-premise infrastructure. I setup a VNET on Azure and needed to connect via Site-to-Site VPN to 4 different on-premise locations.

Naturally, I chose a route-based VPN which could support multi-site connections, but it turns out that one or more of these on-premise VPN devices support only static (policy based) IKEv1 setup. It won't be a problem if I can create a policy based VPN and connection to each client on the VNET but apparently I can only have one VPN per VNET.

What options do I have to be able to connect to these various on-premise locations? Will I need to create multiple VNETs, connect each VNET to an on-premise location with a VPN and join the VNETs with VNET-VNET connection? Is this even possible even though it's becoming messy just typing it.

Appreciate all the help I can get now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE 31/08/2017] The below is not completely accurate anymore.
Now you can have multiple policy-based connections (**IKEv2 only!**) and P2S, Vnet to Vnet, etc on the same gateway. You'll need to deploy one of the new SKUs (VpnGw1, VpnGw2, VpnGw3).

E.g. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-connect-multiple-policybased-rm-ps

---

You can't do Vnet to Vnet with a policy-based gateway, so that's not an option either.

These are probably your best alternatives:

- Deploy a Network Virtual Appliance (NVA) in the VNet (all major network security vendors have options in the Marketplace) and use that in conjunction with [UDR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview) to establish S2S VPNs with all your on-premises locations.
- Deploy a Linux VM and configure your own VPN gateway with some available IPSec software like StrongSwan or similar.
- Use one of the on-premises locations as a VPN hub in a hub and spoke architecture, where the Azure Vnet is one of the spokes. This way you only need one VPN connection between Azure and on-premises, but you still can reach any on-premises locations.
- You could also do a sort of hybrid architecture where any on-premises location that is only compatible with a policy-based VPN is connected to another on-premises location that can do route-based VPN, so you end up having >1 tunnels between Azure and on-premises to not centralize all traffic in one location and to keep all the features a route-based gateway offers (more SKUs, Point to Site VPN, BGP, Coexistence with ExpressRoute, etc) - you could even take advantage of the BGP capabilities and add redundancy to your tunnels to on-premises.

(Disclosure: I work for Microsoft in Azure)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. The last 2 options (doing anything on-premise) is not feasible for me, I have zero control over those. Yes, I had thought of using OpenSwam so thanks a lot for mentioning Strongswan. I have a feeling you put the NVA first for good reasons, so let me explore that first.